How can I increase the bitrate in the following circuit?
Ok, I am trying the following circuit: https://www.instructables.com/Sending-Messages-Using-Lasers-With-Arduino/ But with the LM358 it uses I cannot reach huge bitrate... I am searching ways to increase bitrate to 500,000 bits/sec or more. I cannot believe that only the change of the slew rate of new op-amp will increase the bitrate. So, my question is what else should I change to the circuit in order to reach the most bitrate the circuit can give to me?

The article seems to mention how the current values are calculated and what components should be changed. Which part of the article is unclear?

Sorry, but nowhere says what slew rate do I need for 0.5Mbit/s or 1Mbit/s for example. How to calculate this?

2 Mbps NRZ signal with 5V levels is basically a 1 MHz sine wave of 5Vpp. A 1 MHz 5Vpp sine wave has slew rate of about 32V/us. If the opamp needs to e.g. amplify a 1Vpp signal to 5Vpp, it needs 5 MHz GBW. It may make sense to buy optical receiver modules than build them yourself. IRDA was invented decades ago and should be available.

For some reason I need to use laser link! Thank you so much for your help!

Laser does not rule out IRDA receiver or vice versa. Or TOSLINK receiver. They go up to tens of megabits.

@Justme even more: the simple SFP+ 10GBase-SR transceivers that you can get for 10 – 20 € new are really just laser diodes attached to a differential input pair, and they have bandwidths exceeding what's necessary for 10.3125 billion pulses per second. (That will, however, exceed what one could do on breadboard by a factor of more than 1000×; the limit here comes not from the optics, not even from the electronics driving them like here, but from the inadequate construction method "solderless breadboard")

@MarcusMüller I agree. While SFP modules would not perform a visible laser link if that is a requirement, but using them will be a challenge as they likely require a certain minimum bit rate which could be very high. Like Toslink receivers require minimum of 100kbps to operate properly. That circuit should be thrown out and started from scratch based on what's the intention to do with it.

Because for 32V/us slew rate, every op-amp I see via google search cannot be soldered by hand, what slew rate do I need for 500kbit/s? So, maybe I find a op-amp capable for hand soldering....

@5Volts I've soldered nearly all opamp circuits I've built by hand; I don't think your research is any good if all you can find a chip-scale packages. Opamps are typically used with bandwidths that are rather friendly to large and easy-to-solder packages.

@5Volts to stress what Justme said: you don't need to adapt that circuit. It makes no sense for your use case; you need to design one – based on your requirements. But you're being "cagey" about your requirements ("For some reason…" great, then we can't help you if you can't explain what your design criteria are), so it's impossible to help you from ground up.

Come on! I just chose a method I like from electronics' point of view...I like lasers and I want to use them for my device. Nothing strange at all...

That's cool, and you need to write down all requirements from an electronics point of view!

Ok, the distance will be 2 meters between the 2 tranceivers. I need to achieve a bitrate of 500 kbps. The devices operate at 5 Volts. What else?

Instead of FQP33N10 which has not been in production, which else MOSFET can I use?
